# Polymorphic assignment operator from base and derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, assignment-operator

I would like to be able to copy either a derived or a base object to a derived object, and I would like the correct operator to be chosen polymorphically depending on the type of the copied object.

This code does not work, I would like `b1 = (A&)b2;` to use `B & operator= (B const &other)` because `b2` is a `B`, but it uses `B & operator= (A const &other)`:

```
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A & operator= (A const &other) {
        // Here copy A members...
        cout<<"A to A"<<endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

class B: public A {
public: 
    B & operator= (A const &other) {
        A::operator=(other); // Copy A members.
        cout<<"A to B"<<endl;
        return *this;
    }
    B & operator= (B const &other) {
        A::operator=(other); // Copy A members.
        // Here copy B members...
        cout<<"B to B"<<endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B b1, b2;
    A a2;
    b1 = b2;
    cout<<endl; 
    b1 = (A&)b2;
    cout<<endl; 
    b1 = a2;
    cout<<endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

I guess I have to make something `virtual` but I don't find how.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: "_I would like `b1 = (A&)b2`; to use `B & operator= (B const &other)` because `b2` is a `B`_" Sure.. `b2` is a `B`. But.. `(A&)b2` is `A&`.

Comment: This is pretty much not needed in polymorphism.  Normally you would have smart pointers to the objects and assignment of those pointers is trivial.  If you need a "copy" then you make a virtual `clone` function that provides a new smart pointer that contains a copy of whatever is being pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

*I would like to be able to copy either a derived or a base object to a derived object,* That is a symptom of poor design.

It's better to strive for a design where the only the leaf-level classes in a class hierarchy are instantiable. This allows you to have clean, non-`virtual`, assignment operator functions deal only with objects of right type.

```
class A {
   public:

      // Make A uninstantiable.
      virtual ~A() = 0;

      A & operator= (A const &other) {
         // Here copy A members...
         cout<<"A to A"<<endl;
         return *this;
      }
};

class B: public A {
   public: 

      // Not necessary.
      // B & operator= (A const &other) { ... }

      B & operator= (B const &other) {
         A::operator=(other); // Copy A members.
         // Here copy B members...
         cout<<"B to B"<<endl; 
         return *this;
      }
};
```